# NLP: how to organize this research into Tensorflow

Tags: nlp, tensorflow

I need a network with the following organization:

- the input text, it is constant for training, for example "mama soap frame sponge" or the formulas of physics, math, chemistry and others
- a series of questions (who, where, when, what, whom, what, for what), for example "who washed the frame?"
- A series of answers (labels), for example, the answer "Mom".

How to do it with TensorFlow?

Thank you

Comment: This is complex topic, and not going to be possible to answer on the site, unless you can show more detail about the task and explain the parts of the problem that already understand (and thus don't need help with). You may be better off doing some self-study first in order to be ready to tackle your problem and ask more specific questions. Andrew Ng's course on RNNs might be useful material: https://www.coursera.org/learn/nlp-sequence-models/

Comment: about Question Answering Dynamic NeuralNetworks (great from Stanford) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3octNTE7Is&list=PL3FW7Lu3i5Jsnh1rnUwq_TcylNr7EkRe6&index=16

Comment: Yes that is a great resource. I hope you can see, as it is part of nearly 20 hours of MSc-level lectures, why I thought it was not possible to condense the content into an answer in a few paragraphs on the site. However, if when you try to follow the lectures, you get stuck on some detail, then here would be a good place to ask about that.

Comment: !   a grammar created from a pair of dozen letters, a more complicated thing, do not close the topic

Comment: I found a suitable example from Keras examples  (examples/babi_memnn.py)